# Multiple microservices in one docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have a spring-boot application named '**RestAPI**' which acts as backend service for my UI.
The RestAPI has become a bit complex... so I need to break it down in microservices.

The RestAPI has following functionalities I would like to convert to microservices:

1. Service 1 - Service for basic operations of Protocol 1.
2. Service 2 - Service for basic operations of Protocol 2.
3. Service 3 - Service for complex operations of Protocol 1.
4. Service 4 - Service for complex operations of Protocol 2.

Note - Just a thought... not finalized if I will follow the above mentioned steps.
But need microservices that is final.

The main question is...
Currently I am using 1 docker container for the RestAPI application.
So.. if I break the RestAPI into microservices will it be a good approach to run all the microservices in one docker container ?

If yes.. how can I achieve it using 1 Docker file or multiple Docker files ?

If no.. why is it not feasible ?

Comment: If you stuff services in a single container you have gained nothing and haven't understood microservices. The only thing you gained is more complexity of a single application.

Comment: Ok.. thanks... but I already have 9 containers and don't want to add more containers...
Can you please suggest me some other way... ?

Comment: We have a couple of hundred containers, why is that the limitation. Each service should have its own container. If not then don't make them seperated services but just a structured monolith.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microservices offer several advantages, such as agility, flexible scaling, continuous deployment, maintainability, testability, independent deployability, technology flexibility, and high reliability. They promote agile ways of working, enabling teams to experiment with new features and allowing for fast and easy independent deployment of individual features. Additionally, microservices provide technology flexibility, high reliability, and increase team autonomy.

However, if all microservices run in the same container, they will use the same resources, which can result in something like a monolithic application. To avoid this, each microservice must have its own CPU, memory resources, database, storage, etc. While it is possible to run multiple microservices in the same container, it is not recommended.

To manage each microservice independently, each one should have its own Docker container, which can be orchestrated using Docker Compose or Kubernetes. To achieve this, a Dockerfile must be created for each microservice. The services can also be deployed on AWS Lambda, GCP Cloud Run, App Engine, and other platforms.

[image: Microservice vs Monolith]
Source: https://mintymint.net/blog/tech/microservices-vs-monolithic-software-architecture-guide/

Here is some more useful information:

- [What is Microservices Architecture? AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/microservices/)
- [What is Microservices Architecture? GCP](https://cloud.google.com/learn/what-is-microservices-architecture)
- [Pattern: Microservice Architecture](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html)
- [Microservices vs. monolithic architecture](https://www.atlassian.com/microservices/microservices-architecture/microservices-vs-monolith)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description !!

Answer (score 0):

besides the Advantage, if you are curious to run all your Service In One Container.
FYI:- Not Advisable to use in PROD

```
COPY start.sh /apps/start.sh
RUN  chmod 755 /apps/start.sh
COPY path/target/service1.jar /apps/project1/service1.jar
COPY path/target/service2.jar /apps/project2/service2.jar
COPY path/target/service3.jar /apps/project3/service3.jar
COPY path/target/service4.jar /apps/project4/service4.jar
COPY path/target/service5.jar /apps/project5/service5.jar


EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/apps/start.sh"]
```

Start.sh

```
nohup java -jar -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Dspring.profiles.active=${ENVIRONMENT} /apps/project1/service1.jar > service1.log &
nohup java -jar -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Dspring.profiles.active=${ENVIRONMENT} /apps/project2/service2.jar > service2.log &
nohup java -jar -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Dspring.profiles.active=${ENVIRONMENT} /apps/project3/service3.jar > service3.log &
nohup java -jar -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Dspring.profiles.active=${ENVIRONMENT} /apps/project4/service4.jar > service4.log &
nohup java -jar -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Dspring.profiles.active=${ENVIRONMENT} /apps/project5/service5.jar > service5.log &

make sure to run httpd proxy to direct the calls to right MS
```